# How to I create a github pages site at the home directory?

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Does anyone know how setup a github pages site at your home directory so that instead of username.github.io/repo_name it would be username.github.io? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites

> To publish a user site, you must create a repository owned by your user account that's named `username.github.io`.

That is, the full URL of your repository must be `https://github.com/username/username.github.io`.